# Ask system password to perform a task

Tags: vb.net

So let's say there is a software where user can create username/password and login with that.

Now, I want to let the user change the password only if they can enter the **system password**.  I got this idea from google chrome, where you have to enter the system password to view the saved password.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by **system password** ... Windows?  Why should they need to know that in order to change the user password?

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Should it be done that way is a more debatable question.

Comment: @Plutonix I mean the password which user used to login to his computer. I need to know this password so the software will be more secure

Comment: It would be better to employ security questions.

Comment: I have also added security questions and I bet there are 100 ways to make it secure but I just want to know how did the google chrome did it so I could too

Comment: `I need to know this password so the software will be more secure`, IMHO you do not and ***it would be less secure***. I would just confirm they enter the correct password...

Comment: Let's say I have given a certain person the username and password of the software  but I don't want to let him change the password. Let's assume he also knows the security question and answer. What now?

Comment: Well, there's your problem: dont give out *your* username and password.  Create a new account in "the software"

Comment: so you're trying to say you don't know how to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everyone has pointed out, this is a bad idea. However, if you understand the risks and you are sure you really want to do this:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Dim valid As Boolean = False

Using context As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
    valid = context.ValidateCredentials(Environment.Username, password)
End Using
```

This assumes the machine is on a domain. If it is not and you want to validate against the local machine, then change `ContextType.Domain` to `ContextType.Machine`.

Also, you will need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Comment: You may need to mention that the OP needs to add reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and then import the namespace... `Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.